# Fragment tab content not shown with HoloEverywhere and ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

Hi I'm making this app with two fragments that you can swipe between. The code compiles and runs without crashing and both tabs are shown and you can swipe between the tabs but the tabs have no content. I think this is a problem with the fragments trying to setcontentview. If you need anymore info just ask :)

my main activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SwipeTabsMainActivity extends Activity {
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
TextView tabCenter;
TextView tabText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Stopwatch"),StopWatchFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Timer"), CountdownFragment.class, null);



}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
}
```

the Main Activity's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

my countdown timer fragment

```
import org.holoeverywhere.app.Fragment;
import org.holoeverywhere.internal._View;
import org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceManager;
import org.holoeverywhere.preference.SharedPreferences;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Button;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class CountdownFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnChronometerTickListener {
TextView second, hour, minute;
ImageButton hourup, hourdown, minuteup, minutedown, secondup, seconddown;
Button start, stop;
int hourCount, minCount, secCount;
Context c;
Chronometer count;
boolean viberate, running;
Vibrator v;
boolean startstopshow;
SharedPreferences getPrefs;
View fv = getView();
RelativeLayout rl;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initilize(c);
    setClicker();
    count.start();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    c = getActivity();




}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown, container, false);
     rl = (RelativeLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown, container, false);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}



private void initilize(Context c) {
    hourup = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.hourup);
    minuteup = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.minuteup);
    secondup = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.secondup);
    hourdown = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.hourdown);
    minutedown = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.minutedown);
    seconddown = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.seconddown);
    start = (Button) rl.findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) rl.findViewById(R.id.stop);
    second = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.second);
    minute = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.minute);
    hour = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.hour);
    hourCount = 0;
    minCount = 0;
    secCount = 0;

    count = (Chronometer) rl.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    v = (Vibrator) c.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    running = false;
    getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
}

@Override
public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
    switch (chronometer.getId()) {

    case (R.id.chronometer1):
        secCount--;
        updateDisplay();
        break;
    }
}

}
```

my fragments xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/hourup"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/minuteup"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/secondup"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00 : "
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/minute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00 : "
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/hourdown"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/minutedown"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/seconddown"
            style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <org.holoeverywhere.internal._View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?dividerVertical" />

        <org.holoeverywhere.internal._View
            android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
            android:background="?dividerVertical" />

        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            style="@style/Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stop"
            android:text="Start" />

        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            style="@style/Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:text="Stop" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    android:textSize="0px"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you paste some screen shots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

You have to replace : super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); to your countdown view :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown, container, false);
     rl = (RelativeLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown, container, false);

    return  v;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i can see that you are using the ActionBarSherlock. try that library : http://viewpagerindicator.com/ . It will help you and it is really easy to customize you tabs and navigation

You can see alot of examples with the app on Google play : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS52aWV3cGFnZXJpbmRpY2F0b3Iuc2FtcGxlIl0.

Here's an example :
main activity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 


         mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

            //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        TabPageIndicator tabIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        tabIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);


         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }


}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private Fragment[] fragments;
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "frag A","frag B", "frag C" };

    // Reference : https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager/downloads


    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.fragments = new Fragment[] { new FragmentA(),
                new FragmentB(),
                new FragmentC()};
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fragments[arg0];


    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return this.fragments.length;

    }


}
```

FragmentX :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);


        return v;


    }

}
```

main xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.viewpagertest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.viewpagertest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Using that library doesn't help I think the problem might be with the fragment itself.

Comment: I understand, but it is much easier to implement a viewpager with indicators with that library. Im gonna try to debug your code and post another answer to help you out